# Can't find VersionControlExt using VS2013

Tags: tfs, vspackage

I want to code a VSPackage and need to get the selected items from Source Control Explorer History. I'm pretty sure that I need VersionControlExt, but I can't find the namespace Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl using Visual Studio 2013. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a NuGet package [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/). I'm not sure if these are too new to work against VS2013 but it's easiest to test.

If the NuGet package doesn't work, you can get the DLLs on your machine. These DLLs are stored in the Private Assembly cache of Visual Studio. You can edit the register to allow Visual Studio to search through these folders. See the first step of this post for details: [Step 1: Help Visual Studio Find Team Foundation Assemblies](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edhintz/archive/2006/02/03/524312.aspx)